# Django ifequal not working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication, django-templates, django-errors

This is my registration form:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password (Again)', widget=forms.PasswordInput())

def clean_password2(self):
    if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data:
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 == password2:
            return password2
    raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')

def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    if not re.search(r'^\w+$', username): #checks if all the characters in username are in the regex. If they aren't, it returns None
        raise forms.ValidationError('Username can only contain alphanumeric characters and the underscore.')
    try:
        User.objects.get(username=username) #this raises an ObjectDoesNotExist exception if it doesn't find a user with that username
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return username #if username doesn't exist, this is good. We can create the username
    raise forms.ValidationError('Username is already taken.')
```

and this is my template:

```
{% if form.errors %}

    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.label_tag == "Password (Again)" %}
            <p>The passwords which you entered did not match.</p>
        {% else %}
            {{ field.label_tag }} : {{ field.errors }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I basically want to say

```
The passwords which you entered did not match.
```

if Django returns an error for the password2 field. I did say in the RegistrationForm that

```
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password (Again)'
```

but Django goes straight to the else statement and when it executes the line

```
{{ field.label_tag }} : {{ field.errors }}
```

and when I check the web browser, it says

```
Password (Again) : This field is required.
```

So

```
field.label_tag
```

does equal

```
"Password (Again)"
```

right? How come my

```
if field.label_tag == "Password (Again)"
```

statement is not evaluating to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in the browser is not what `field.label_tag` really is.

Actually `field.label_tag` is something like this (you can look at the HTML source):

```
<label for="id_password2">Password (Again):</label>
```

To quote a great man (and Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)):

> {{ field.label_tag }} The field’s label wrapped in the appropriate
>   HTML  tag.

This code should work:

```
{% if field.label_tag == '<label for="id_password2">Password (Again):</label>' %}
etc
```

Now, obviously, nobody wants to write code like this. Strings with the HTML code? Come on, Nigel, you're better than this!

Here is the better way:

```
{% if field.name == 'password2' %}
etc
```

Actually, I think there is even a better way to handle form errors. You can read the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).